# How to change the ringtone for SMS in Samsung Galaxy Y?

Tags: ringtone, samsung-galaxy-y

Is there a way to change the ringtone for SMS in Samsung Galaxy Y, Gingerbread v2.3.6?

Comment: It's not working @geffchang.

Comment: What step did not work?

Comment: The last one did'nt work.

Comment: Do you see Select Ringtone?

Comment: Yes. But the ringtones in my files are not appearing

Comment: Is it an MP3 file?

Comment: Yes has an extension .mp3

Comment: What if you restart phone, and then check Select Ringtone again?

Comment: Tried it... not working.. Anyway thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open `My Files`.
- Create a new folder (e.g. Notifications)
- Copy MP3 files to newly-created folder
- Go to SMS message
- Select `Menu > Settings > Select Ringtone`